# requirejs dependencies load order doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, requirejs, loader, amd

I have such a code:

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        mods: 'default',
        myFriend: 'myFriend',
        myCoworker: 'myCoworker'
    },
    shim: {
        mods: ['myFriend', 'myCoworker']
    }
});
require(['mods'], function (mods) {
    // something to do
});
```

and modules which are the dependencies:

myFriend.js

```
var mess = `<a really huge text, almost 200 Kbytes>`
console.log('This code is ran in the myFriend module...', {mess:mess});
```

myCoworker.js

```
console.log('This code is ran in the myCoworker module...');
var wrk = {
    name: 'John'
};
```

So I hope, that accordingly to shim is should always load myFriend.js (that is checked by console.output) before myCoworker.js. But it doesn't. The console output shows:

```
This code is run in the myCoworker module...
```

and then

```
This code is run in the myFriend module...
```

Probably I have missed something, but what?

The entire code is here: http://embed.plnkr.co/zjQhBdOJCgg8QuPZ5Q8A/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dealing with a fundamental misconception in how RequireJS works. We use `shim` for files that do not call `define`. Using `shim` makes it so that RequireJS will, so to speak, add a kind of "virtual define" to those files. The shim you show is equivalent to:

```
define(['myFriend', 'myCoworker'], function (...) {...});
```

**The dependency list passed to a `define` or `require` call does not, in and of itself, specifies a loading order *among* the modules listed in the dependency list.** The only thing the dependency list does is specify that the modules in the list must be loaded before calling the callback. That's all.

If you want `myFriend` to load first, you need to make `myCoworker` dependent on it:

```
shim: {
    mods: ['myFriend', 'myCoworker'],
    myCoworker: ['myFriend'],
}
```

By the way, `shim` is really meant to be used for code you do not control. For your own code you should be using `define` in your code *instead of* setting a `shim` in the configuration.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. The thing which I really don't understand yet is -- what such a seemingly verbose syntax is used for. Why not to define the order of loading just in the field 'mods'? Probably there is a reason for that, of course, but it is not quite clear for me. Do you have any idea? Thank you, anyway!

Comment: If the dependency list *also* defined the order *among* the modules in the list, you'd be overspecifying the order in which modules are loaded. Let's take two popular libraries: jQuery and Lodash. jQuery does not depend on Lodash, and Lodash does not depend on jQuery. If I write a module that uses both, then my dependency list is `["jquery", "lodash"]`. The way RequireJS works, it resolves both module names to URLs and requests both in parallel. Let's say the server that holds the jQuery module is slower than the server that holds the Lodash module. (to be continued...)

Comment: (... continued) With the current dependency semantics, it does not matter if Lodash resolves first, RequireJS just loads it first and will then load jQuery when it is ready. However, if the dependency list also established an order among the modules in the list, then even if Lodash resolved first, RequireJS would have to wait until jQuery resolves, then load jQuery, then load Lodash. However, the extra wait is 100% unnecessary because it is perfectly fine to load Lodash first. Given that one of the concerns that RequireJS addresses is optimizing load time, this would be a problem.